# How to control priority of class specification

Tags: css

I have some DOM elements that have classes `foo` and `bar`:

```
<div class="foo bar">...</div>
```

and I want to control the priority between them. Following the [w3c specification on this](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity), I thought that adding extra selectors to the css might make the priority higher. For example, if I wanted `foo` to override `bar`, I was thinking of putting a `dummy` class like this:

```
.foo, .dummy{
  ...
}

.bar{
  ...
}
```

Will this work? Is there a better way to do this? I know that `!important` can control individual attributes, but I want a more general solution that controls the priority of the entire class specification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you first add a rule for the .bar class and then for the .foo, .foo rules will overide .bar's

example:

```
.bar {
    color : red;
}

.foo {
    color: blue;
}
```

The color of the div will be blue.

What you proposed will work, but you need to add the dummy class to the div (so the css selector will match)

example:

```
<div class="foo bar dummy">...</div>
```